# Change CSS font size dynamically across application, based on user preference

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a requirement to change the font size in application based on the user entered entry?  I know about CSS variables and using it in all classes, but this has limited support across browsers.

For example, a user prefers 14px then all control and text font-size should change to 14px.

Can you please give me an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Share what have you tried so far.

Comment: When it comes to sharing what you've tried, please read the "*[ask]*" and "*[mcve]*" guidelines, and then [edit] your question.

Comment: Use `em` and `rem` as font sizes. I think there is little need to set it in your app, the browser has settings for font-sizes(which work if you use `em` and `rem`) and users who are sighted can also use zoom.

Answer (score 1):

Use font-size in REM. 1 Rem used base font-size of html. see this code

```js
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];

var input = document.getElementById('font-size');

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
 html.style.fontSize = ""+e.target.value+"px";
  console.log(html.style.fontSize)
})
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati rerum numquam, dolorem ad ducimus. Commodi provident mollitia labore voluptatum itaque quasi eligendi, ipsam obcaecati nostrum cum aperiam doloremque ab consectetur?<p>

<input id="font-size" type="text" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give font-size to body as dynamically you can achieve this

```js
function setFont()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("font");
  if(!(x.value>0))
  {
    alert("Enter valid input");
    
  } 
  else
  {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.fontSize=x.value +"px" ;
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
 <input id="font" placeholder="Enter Font size" type="number" />
  <input type="button" value="Set" onclick="setFont()"/>
  
  
  <p>Example paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.getElementById('text');
var inp = document.getElementById('font-size');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
x = window.getComputedStyle(a, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
currentsize = parseFloat(x)
a.style.fontSize = (inp.value) + 'px';
})
```

```html
<p id='text'>text content <p>
<input id="font-size" type="text" value="">
<button id='btn'>set</button>
```